# Detect from mobile Chrome if a specific application is installed

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, frontend

I am looking for a way to check if a App is installed in IOS/Andriod when using Chrome browser. I knew there's an easy way for Safari by adding a  tag inside the  tag like this:

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=XXXXYYYY">`

However, it won't work at all with Chrome.

I tried [getInstalledRelatedApps()](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/#supported-app-types-you-can-check) but it didn't work. I am not sure if I used it correctly. After adding information in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `strings.xml` from Andriod App. I added `manifest.json` and served from the root. There's a problem that I cannot debug by using `navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps();` in my desktop Chrome. It always showed 0 length. I tried to add `alert()` when `getInstalledRelatedApps()` find my app id which using

```
const installedApps = await navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps();
const nativeApp = installedApps.find(app => app.id === 'com.XXX.android');

if (nativeApp) {
  alert('There’s an installed native app')
}
```

but it didn't show any alert when I using my App.

Plus, I do have an Android app and IOS app. It seems `getInstalledRelatedApps()` can be used for my Android app only?

Anyone have good idea for Detect App is installed when I using Chrome Browser? Many thanks.

Comment: Debugging would be easier if you use Chrome on Android. Use Chrome remote debugging for connecting desktop Chrome to Android Chrome. Based on the description it may be that it only works for apps installed via Google Play Store.